# When building Electron: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: html5lib

Tags: electron

When following the directions at https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/development/build-instructions-gn I am getting the following error when building:

```
C:\git\electron\src>ninja -C out/Release electron
ninja: Entering directory `out/Release'
[2312/46258] ACTION //third_party/catapult/tracing:generate_about_tracing(//build/toolchain/win:win_clang_x64)
FAILED: gen/content/browser/tracing/about_tracing.js gen/content/browser/tracing/about_tracing.html
C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.exe ../../third_party/catapult/tracing/bin/generate_about_tracing_contents --outdir gen/content/browser/tracing
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\git\electron\src\third_party\catapult\common\py_vulcanize\py_vulcanize\html_module.py", line 28, in Parse
    parser_results = parse_html_deps.HTMLModuleParser().Parse(self.contents)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\git\electron\src\third_party\catapult\common\py_vulcanize\py_vulcanize\parse_html_deps.py", line 298, in Parse
    return HTMLModuleParserResults(html)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\git\electron\src\third_party\catapult\common\py_vulcanize\py_vulcanize\parse_html_deps.py", line 164, in __init__
    self._soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html5lib')
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\git\electron\src\third_party\catapult\third_party\beautifulsoup4-4.9.3\py3k\bs4\__init__.py", line 243, in __init__
    raise FeatureNotFound(
bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: html5lib. Do you need to install a parser library?

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\git\electron\src\third_party\catapult\tracing\bin\generate_about_tracing_contents", line 14, in <module>
    sys.exit(generate_about_tracing_contents.Main(sys.argv[1:]))
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\git\electron\src\third_party\catapult\tracing\tracing_build\generate_about_tracing_contents.py", line 32, in Main
    load_sequence = vulcanizer.CalcLoadSequenceForModuleNames(names)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\git\electron\src\third_party\catapult\common\py_vulcanize\py_vulcanize\project.py", line 146, in CalcLoadSequenceForModuleNames
    modules = [self.loader.LoadModule(module_name=name,
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\git\electron\src\third_party\catapult\common\py_vulcanize\py_vulcanize\resource_loader.py", line 145, in LoadModule
    m.Parse(excluded_scripts)
  File "C:\git\electron\src\third_party\catapult\common\py_vulcanize\py_vulcanize\html_module.py", line 30, in Parse
    raise Exception('While parsing %s: %s' % (self.name, str(ex)))
Exception: While parsing tracing.ui.extras.about_tracing.about_tracing: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: html5lib. Do you need to install a parser library?
[2329/46258] CXX obj/third_party/swiftshader/src/Reactor/swiftshader_subzero/Path.obj
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I verified that I have html5lib installed:

```
C:\git\electron\src>pip list
Package        Version
-------------- -------
beautifulsoup4 4.12.2
bs4            0.0.1
html5lib       1.1
lxml           4.9.3
pip            23.2.1
six            1.16.0
soupsieve      2.5
webencodings   0.5.1
```

Just in case I did run these commands:

```
pip install bs4
pip install html5lib
pip install lxml
```

But this didn't help. I am currently using Python 3.12.1.

Does anybody know how I may resolve this issue?